# android studio use cleartext http on api 17

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I am using `xammp` server for `php` on `localhost` , i was working before update (i think), but now http connection gives me an exception:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to
> 192.168.0.105 not permitted

i have tried then to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on `Application` for `AndroidManifest` , but also a next error:

> Attribute usesCleartextTraffic is only used in API level 23 and higher (current min is 17)

I want to keep support to `API 17`, and when releasing my app I will use https on a public server, what can I do for now?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning.

Comment: but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to set minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion of your app to 23 (Android Marshmallow) to use android:usesCleartextTraffic. On older platforms, this attribute is simply ignored and thus has no effect.

Reference - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/protecting-against-unintentional.html?m=1